# Steam fatal error steam needs to be online to update, but was set to offline movies

Tags: 12.10, ati, steam

I tried to install steam but is impossible to run it

I get this when I try to run it

```
steam
Running Steam on ubuntu 12.10 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
ILocalize::AddFile() failed to load file "public/steambootstrapper_english.txt".
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(0_client)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1.0_client)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1.0_client)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1.0_client)
SteamUpdater: Error: Download failed: http error 0SteamUpdater: Error: Steam needs to be online to update.  Please confirm your network connection and try again.
Installing bootstrap /home/elin3t/.local/share/Steam/bootstrap.tar.xz
Running Steam on ubuntu 12.10 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME has been set by the user to: /home/elin3t/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime
ILocalize::AddFile() failed to load file "public/steambootstrapper_english.txt".
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(0_client)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1.0_client)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1.0_client)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1.0_client)
SteamUpdater: Error: Download failed: http error 0
SteamUpdater: Error: Steam needs to be online to update.  Please confirm your network connection and try again.
```

and this is my hardware VGA

```
lspci | grep VGA
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RV710 [Radeon HD 4350]
```

And this my distro version

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.10
Release:    12.10
Codename:   quantal
```

thanks if some can help me!!

I tried the forum solution but I didnt found the **registry.vdf** file to change the lines

Comment: I'm obliged to ask you this: Do you have Internet connection and is working fine?

Comment: of course and I have a ping in to one terminal tab to test it! and all is good! (about internet connection)

Comment: this are the estadistics for that while i tryed to run steam **197 packets transmitted, 197 received, 0% packet loss, time 196192ms**

Comment: That comment removed my doubts :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the solution with this

```
cd .steam/
rm steam.pid
cd
rm .steampid

sudo apt-get install xfonts-100dpi xfonts-75dpi
```

Then run steam again!

if it doesn't work at first, restart

Answer (score 2):

I solve the problem in my laptop with the command:

```
steam --reset
```

my laptop is an acer aspire 5742G with an intel core i5-480m and an Nvidia Geforce GT 540m, I use bumblebee to avoid optimus problems.